# Путь к файлу. В чем разница между "../" и "./"?

Tags: файлы, webpack

"../" означает вернуться на одну директорию назад, но что при этом означает "./" непонятно и когда смотрю примеры разных конфигов то "./" сбивает с толку.

вот пример, кусок кода из конфигурационного файла webpack’a:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './assets/js/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'.'` означает обозначение текущего каталога.

`'..'` означает родительский каталог текущего каталога.

Например, если у вас есть следующая структура каталогов, и текщим каталогом является каталог `inner1`

```
outer
  |
  ------> inner1
  |         |
  |         ------> more_inner
  ------> inner2
            |
            ------> more_inner
```

то `.\more_inner` указывает на подкаталог `more_inner` текущего каталога `inner1`.

С другой стороны, путь `..\inner2\more_inner` указывает на подкаталог `more_inner` каталога `inner2`.

Comment: Можно наглядный пример?

Comment: И, если можно, пример того, для чего может пригодиться '.\'

Comment: @ЛысакМаксим Наглядный пример чего? пример использования `./` есть в приведённом Вами коде. С `../` Вы разобрались.

Comment: @ЛысакМаксим Смотрите мой обновленный ответ.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ!